# Complile file .as and .fla to export .swf

Tags: flash

Im use Sothink SWF Decompile, and take .fla and .as  . How to compile .as and .fla by Adobe Flash?  help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adobe Flash to open .fla and publish it.